# Trying to open a web page in standard fullscreen with address bar from a pop-up window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a pop-up window using javascript from my index.html page that pops up a form -

When the user completes the form & submits in the pop-up it returns to my results.html web page to the browser without address, status bars and all standard fullscreen default elements.   What is the correct javascript I need to use to accomplish this?

the java script from the index.html first page:

```
             <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">>          
             function popup(mylink, windowname) {
            if (! window.focus)
              return true;
             var href;
            if (typeof(mylink) == 'string')
              href=mylink;
             else
             href=mylink.href;
             window.open(href, windowname, 'width=800,height=400,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=no,menubar=no');
           return false;
           }
        </script>
<body>
        <a href="pageform2.html" onClick="return popup(this, 'notes');">pop up form page</a>
```

...and the results.html page return (which I need fullscreen with the all standard webpage elements) has:

```
     function resizePageFullScreen(){
     window.moveTo(0,0) ;
     window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight);
      }

      <body onload="resizePageFullScreen();">
```

... this is returning full screen but does not contain the standard webpage elements like the address,status,scroll etc.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

"If the strWindowFeatures parameter is used, the features that are not listed will be disabled or removed (except titlebar and close which are by default yes)." - source [MDN, window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Since `location` is not included as one of the [features string options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Toolbar_and_chrome_features) in the posted code, the address bar will not be displayed.

Note that full screening a page - without browser window controls such as maximize, minimize or close - is disabled in some (most?) browsers.

Try changing the window open call to be similar to:

```
    window.open(href, windowname,
       'width=800,height=400,scrollbars,resizable,location,status');
```

and include *all* the window options you want to be available.